# Как синхронизировать работу потоков по инкрементации переменной цикла?

Tags: java, многопоточность, concurrency

Сущетвует ли возможность синхронизировать инкрементацию переменной, чтобы подхватывая значения i поток работал с ним дальше по коду, а следующий поток, использовал бы переменную i со следующим значением (i+1). 
т.е есть цикл и в нем потоки должны  работать с элементами ArrayList :

```
 for ( int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println(arrayList.get(i));
      newArrayList.add(arrayList.get(i));
    }
```

Проблема в том, что не получается заставить потоки хватать уникальные значения i , и потоки работают с одинаковыми данными...

Comment: Если вам нужно синхронизировать переменную типа int, то воспользуйтесь классом `java.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger`

Comment: Может объявить ее final?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потоки сами могут инкрементировть переменную и выбирать себе нужный элемент массива.
Если для простоты рабочие потоки одноразовые, и массив в процессе не меняется, то сделать это можно таким образом:

```
    // создаем массив с данными (например с числами 1-100)
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=1; i<=100; i++) list.add(i);

    // объявляем и инициализируем потокобезопасную переменную счетчика
    final AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger(-1);

    // описываем поток который будет работать с элементом массива
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int element = list.get(n.incrementAndGet()); // поток будет самостоятельно инкрементировать счетчик
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " get element " + element); // и что то делать с элементом
        }
    };

    // запускаем потоки по количеству элементов массива
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        service.submit(r);
    }

    service.shutdown(); // даем всем потокам доработать
```